# How do I filter lines based on their first word in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm having a bit of a tough time defining a function that parses a bunch of strings and filters for strings of the form:

```
v 3.0 2.0 3.7
```

where the `v` is the identifier. There are a bunch of identifiers (`vt`, `f`, etc.) but I am only interested in the ones starting with a `v`.

The function header looks like:

```
readOBJVerts :: [String] -> [Point]
```

and I have this so far:

```
readOBJVerts lines = [(x,y,z) | line <- lines,
                      let x = read (coords !! 1) :: GLDouble
                          y = read (coords !! 2) :: GLDouble
                          z = read (coords !! 3) :: GLDouble
                          coords = splitOn " " line
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
Main.hs: Prelude.read: no parse
Main.hs: interrupted
```

I believe this is because my function does not currently filter for only the `v` lines. So it's attempting to parse lines like:

```
f 1/2 2/1 3/4
```

which doesn't bode well for the `read` function.

What's the easiest way to filter for lines only beginning with a specific word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a haskell comprehension, you can add boolean expressions to it, so that any values that do not match the expression are not included in the final result. Eg `[x | x <- [1..10], even x ]` returns `[2,4,5,6,10]`. This allows a simple adjustment to your function so it operates like you want:

```
readOBJVerts lines = [(x,y,z) | line <- lines,
                      let x = read (coords !! 1) :: GLDouble
                          y = read (coords !! 2) :: GLDouble
                          z = read (coords !! 3) :: GLDouble
                          coords = splitOn " " line,
                      (coords !! 0) == "v"]
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I tried that and it threw an error... but maybe placement of the condition matters?

Comment: Yes, it has to be after the let clause, otherwise the `coords` value won't be defined.

Comment: Also, as an aside, you may want to look at [parsec](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsec). This is a parsing library that allows you to parse files but with better error handling, and is more composable.